# React component name from factory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have two components:

```
const CustomSelfDefinedComponent = () => <React.Fragment />;
const CustomSelfDefinedViaFactoryComponent = (() => () => <React.Fragment />)();
```

on shallow rendering I get next:

```
        <CustomSelfDefinedComponent />
        <Component />
```

Can anyone point me why in second case I don't have `CustomSelfDefinedViaFactoryComponent` as a component name in a snapshot?

I see the reason at the fact that it compiles as : [[BABEL PLAYGROUND]](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAwgV2iAtgZQKYBsBmARDHASzAwBM5UAHcDMWAXhgAoBKGBgPhgB4AlDAENgUAHQAxAE6CA5ijqwA9JwDcAKFCRYiZOmz5CJcgDUig8cKghJAT0ooapehxZsO3N114DLE6XIUYZVY2dSA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=)

```
"use strict";

var CustomSelfDefinedComponent = function CustomSelfDefinedComponent() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null);
};

var CustomSelfDefinedViaFactoryComponent = function () {
  return function () {
    return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null);
  };
}();
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose React relies on function.name to get default component name, so in first case

```js
const CustomSelfDefinedComponent = () => <React.Fragment />;
CustomSelfDefinedComponent.name -> "CustomSelfDefinedComponent"
```

while in second anonymous function returned and `name = ""`

To solve that factory function can have explicit displayName argument:

```js
const factory = (..., displayName) => {
  const NewComponent = () => { ... }
  NewComponent.displayName = displayName
  return NewComponent
}
```

not sure if there's a babel plugin that can simplify it

Comment: Same idea, Max =)) Just wondering if there is a better solution